# Possible to join GTA V Heist without high-end apartment and/or less than level 12?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

The requirements for playing the heists are plastered all over the internet:

- Need a high-end apartment with a planning board
- Need to be level 12

However, [some places](http://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/gta-online-heists-guide/) says you need to be level 12 to *host* the heist where as [other places](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/204997567--3-10-15-GTAV-Title-Update-1-21-PS3-Xbox-360-1-07-PS4-Xbox-One-) says that heists unlock at level 12.

What is correct?

A level 6 (example), can he join a heist, provided that someone else that meets the requirements hosts it? Or does everybody need to be level 12 (or higher) and have a high-end apartment?

Comment: While it is possible, I wouldn't recommend it as the amount of weapons and armors people under level 12 (even under 30) make heists after the fleeca bank heist really hard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can join someone else's heist if they invite you, regardless of level or residence.

you only NEED to be level 12 and own an apartment to be the heist LEADER / HOST the heists.

Answer (score 1):

If you are level 12 and own a high-end apartment you will get a call from Lester. He will tell you that it is now possible to join heists and plan them. I am level 4 now and I was able to join my friends on a heist.

Comment: So that last sentence confirms that my level 6 friend will be able to join the rest of us in a heist, provided one of us (except for him, we're all level 30+) hosts the heist, did I understand you correctly then?